Simplifying $\prod_{j=1}^{2n} (1 + n-n\omega^j -\omega^{j(n+1)})$ when $\omega$ is a $(2n+1)$th root of unity
Can we express $$f(n) = \prod_{j=1}^{2n} (1 + n-n\omega^j -\omega^{j(n+1)})$$ in terms of $n$ when $\omega$ is a $(2n+1)$th root of unity?
I arrived at this equation when trying to explicitly express a certain integer quantity of $K_{2n+1}$ (the complete graph on $2n+1$ vertices). I’ve found that we can express this quantity as  $\frac{f(n)}{(2n+1)^2}$. So, $f(n)$ is always divisible by $(2n+1)^2$. For reference, $f(1) = 9$, $f(2) = 275$, and $f(3) = 18571$.

you can factor out $1-\omega^j$ for starters.

Working with the original formulation (i.e. the graph problem) might be easier.

For $\omega$, a $(2n+1)$-th root of unity, we show the following identity is valid
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{j=1}^{2n}\left(1+n-n\omega^j-\omega^{j(n+1)}\right)=(n+1)^{2n+1}+n^{2n+1}\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
The proof is done in three steps. At first we factorize the product into linear factors and then we calculate the so derived products separately.
Factorization: Factorization is carried out using the symmetry properties of the $(2n+1)$-th root of unity and by consequently using $\omega^{2n+1}=1$ to simplify the exponents.

We obtain:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{j=1}^{2n}}&\color{blue}{\left(1+n-n\omega^j-\omega^{j(n+1)}\right)}\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\left(1-\omega^{2j(n+1)}\right)+n\left(1-\omega^{2j}\right)\right)\\
&\qquad\cdot\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\left(1-\omega^{(2j-1)(n+1)}\right)+n\left(1-\omega^{2j-1}\right)\right)\tag{2.1}\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\left(1-\omega^{j}\right)+n\left(1-\omega^{2j}\right)\right)\\
&\qquad\cdot\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\left(1-\omega^{j+n}\right)+n\left(1-\omega^{j+n}\right)\right)\tag{2.2}\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\left(1-\omega^{j}\right)+n\left(1-\omega^{2j}\right)\right)\\
&\qquad\cdot\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\left(1-\omega^{-j}\right)+n\left(1-\omega^{-2j}\right)\right)\tag{2.3}\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1-\omega^j\right)\left(1+n\left(1+\omega^{j}\right)\right)\\
&\qquad\cdot\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1-\omega^{-j}\right)\left(1+n\left(1+\omega^{-j}\right)\right)\tag{2.4}\\
&\color{blue}{=\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1-\omega^j\right)\left(1-\omega^{-j}\right)}\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{\cdot\prod_{j=1}^n\left(n+1+n\omega^j\right)\left(n+1+n\omega^{-j}\right)}\tag{2.5}
\end{align*}
With (2.5) we have found two product representations that are accessible for direct calculation.

Comment:

In (2.1) we split the product into one with even and one with odd indices $j$.

In (2.2) we use $\omega^{2n+1}=1$, as e.g. $\omega^{2j(n+1)}=\left(\omega^{(2n+2)}\right)^j
=\left(\omega^{(2n+2)-(2n+1)}\right)^j=\omega^j$.

In (2.3) we change the order of multiplication in the second product $j\to n-j+1$ and use again $\omega^{2n+1}=1$.

In (2.4) we factor out terms recalling $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

In (2.5) we rearrange the products that can be calculated directly.


First product:
We consider the first product in (2.5) and show the following is valid:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1-\omega^j\right)\left(1-\omega^{-j}\right)=2n+1\qquad\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}}\tag{3.1}
\end{align*}
We recall that given $z^{2n+1}-1=0$ we have a representation as product of linear factors with $j$-th powers of the $(2n+1)$-th root of unity.
\begin{align*}
z^{2n+1}-1=\prod_{j=0}^{2n}\left(z-\omega^j\right)=0\tag{3.2}
\end{align*}
Together with L'Hôpital's rule we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{j=1}^n}&\color{blue}{\left(1-\omega^J\right)\left(1-\omega^{-j}\right)}\\
&=\lim_{z\to 1}\prod_{j=1}^n\left(z-\omega^j\right)\left(z-\omega^{-j}\right)\\
&=\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{z^{2n+1}-1}{z-1}\tag{$\to (3.2)$}\\
&=\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{(2n+1)z^{2n}}{1}\tag{L'Hôpital's rule}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=2n+1}
\end{align*}
and (3.1) follows.
Second product:
We consider the second product in (2.5) and show the following is valid:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{j=1}^n\left(n+1+n\omega^j\right)\left(n+1+n\omega^{-j}\right)
=\frac{(n+1)^{2n+1}+n^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}}\tag{4.1}
\end{align*}
Similarly as above we consider $z^{2n+1}-a^{2n+1}=0$ and the representation as product of linear factors with $j$-th powers of the $(2n+1)$-th root of unity.
\begin{align*}
z^{2n+1}-a^{2n+1}=\prod_{j=0}^{2n}\left(z-a\omega^j\right)=0\tag{4.2}
\end{align*}
We obtain:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{j=1}^n}&\color{blue}{\left(n+1+n\omega^j\right)\left(n+1+n\omega^{-j}\right)}\\
&=(n+1)^{2n}\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+\frac{n}{n+1}\omega^j\right)\left(1+\frac{n}{n+1}\omega^{-j}\right)\\
&=(n+1)^{2n}\,\frac{1+\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{2n+1}}{1+\frac{n}{n+1}}\tag{$\to (4.2)$}\\
&=(n+1)^{2n+1}\,\frac{1+\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2n+1}\left((n+1)^{2n+1}+n^{2n+1}\right)}
\end{align*}
and (4.1) follows and together with (3.1) also the main formula (1).

very nice! it appears I essentially got to (2.3) and then gave up.

@dezdichado: Many thanks. :-)

This is not a solution but it is a solid conjecture: it seems that
$$
f(n) = n^{2n+1} + (n+1)^{2n+1}.
$$
Computationally it matches the first $100$ values of the function.
This formula was discovered by searching the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences for the values $f(4) = 2{,}215{,}269$ and $f(5) = 411{,}625{,}181$ and noticing the coincidence between the appearances of sequences A036087 and A036089, respectively.
Moral of the story—always search on OEIS!

I searched for the sequence ${9, 275, 18571, \ldots}$ on OEIS, but didn't think to search large values individually. I'll be more thorough in the future. I appreciate the help.

no worries, I almost missed that idea too  :p
